# Get value from firestore collection in react native

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

I want to write a function that will get the value for the collection, as shown in the picture:

[image: Firestore collection image]

And here is my code, I really don't know what to do after the "then()":

```
const getLocation = () => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(currentUser.uid)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {});
};
```

**Note** that currentUser is redux, meaning that the query will execute only for the current user that is logged in

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the value of `businessLocation` only you can do this:

```
const getLocation = () => {
    return firebase.firestore()
            .collection("users")
            .doc(currentUser.uid)
            .get()
            .then(function(doc) {
                if (doc.exists) {
                    data = doc.data();
                    return data.businessDetails.businessLocation;
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
            });
};
```

You can get more information on how to get data in firestore at the [Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document).

**Note**: This makes your function become an asynchronous function. Therefore you should call it as follows:

```
getLocation().then(result => {
    //Do whatever you want with the result value
    console.log(result);
})
```